# Log client side error At Server Side Using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

i'm newbie in angular js, have created a project in angular js and want to maintain log on server for all the issues occuring at the client side.

Gone through various blogs and found few suggestions for applying stack js but couldn't understand the implementation for same.

Please suggest if it is possible to log all the errors in project from one single point of client side, at the server through factory or service method using angular js.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly by overriding angulars built in $exceptionHandler. Below is the snippet of code from my own app that logs any failures to the backend, but also prints them into the console, in case the backend logging fails. As my javascript is minified, I use StackTrace to turn this back into an un-minified stack trace, and send that to my backend.

```
function exceptionLoggingService($injector) {
    function error(exception, cause) {

        // preserve the default behaviour which will log the error
        // to the console, and allow the application to continue running.
        var $log = $injector.get('$log');
        var $window = $injector.get('$window');
        $log.error.apply($log, arguments);

        var errorMessage = exception.toString();

        StackTrace.fromError(exception).then(function (arrayStack) {
            var exceptionData = angular.toJson({
                errorUrl: $window.location.href,
                errorMessage: errorMessage,
                stackTrace: arrayStack,
                cause: ( cause || "" )
            });
            // now post this exceptionData to your backend
        }).catch(function (backendLoggingError) {
            $log.warn("Error logging failure.");
            $log.log(backendLoggingError);
        });

    }

    return(error);
}

angular.module('dashboard-ui').factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', exceptionLoggingService])
```